# Facebook SDK - #200: Cannot send notifications

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

```
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
                    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                        'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                    ));

                    $facebook->api("/$user_id/notifications/", 'post', array(
                        'access_token' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                        'template' => "MSG",
                        'href' => "www.google.com",
                    ));
```

*"Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Cannot send notifications to a user who has not installed the app thrown"*

Error occurs after the User remove permissions of the application, there is some means of detecting when the User remove the application, or ignore the error?

Comment: _“or ignore the error?”_ – if you don’t want exceptions to cause fatal errors, then you have to _catch_ them of course.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has a webhook that is triggered when a user uninstalls their Facebook app.

From the documentation [Detecting when people uninstall apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#_4-u3_588p):

> You can enable a deauthorize callback via the [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps). Just go to your app, then choose the **Settings** menu, and finally the **Advanced** tab. A text field is provided for the **Deauthorize Callback URL**.
>
> Whenever a user of your app de-authorizes it, this URL will be sent an `HTTP POST` containing a [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#parsingsr). Read our [guide to parsing the signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#parsingsr) to see how to decode this to find out the user ID that triggered the callback.